# Oracle Java 9 installer fails in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, 16.04, oracle

I'm new to Ubuntu

I tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

but it failed:

```
download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status >1
Errors were encountered while processing:
oracle-java9-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: If you do it without -y, you will see that webupd8team recommend using java 8 as version 9 has issues. I installed java 8 using this method today & it worked fine (but I don't know how to solve your problem for java 9)

Comment: thank u @Zanna but it fails either for 8!
>HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden

>2016-04-29 22:44:57 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

>download failed

Comment: well, at least you have a different error - that is always progress ;) maybe try purging the ppa and starting again, or [like they suggest on the site](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) try downloading the tar then getting the installer

Comment: Seems the file http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/114/binaries/jdk-9-ea+114_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz is truncated at 58Mb

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Seems like this issue was localized...

Comment: I have it, too. No idea what it is.