# Java 9 official release: how to install JDK9 directly?

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk

Java 9 was released officially today, so is there a way to install the JDK on Ubuntu (16.04) without having to change version numbers and checksums?

I was trying to use the `webupd8 oracle-java9-installer`, but each time it failed with the same error message. I followed the recommended solutions posted to these questions, none of them worked for me -

- [Can't install Oracle JDK 9](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938314/cant-install-oracle-jdk-9)
- [oracle-jdk9-installer fails with HTTP 404](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928664/oracle-jdk9-installer-fails-with-http-404)
- [webupd8 oracle-java-9-installer failing with 404](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939384/webupd8-oracle-java-9-installer-failing-with-404)
- [Oracle Java 9 installer fails in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764993/oracle-java-9-installer-fails-in-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Can't install anything because of JDK9 unsuccessful installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944774/cant-install-anything-because-of-jdk9-unsuccessful-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I get the same error message that others have mentioned, even after following the recommended steps.

```
...Downloading Oracle Java 9... --2017-09-22 02:51:55--  http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/181/binaries/jdk-9+181_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Resolving download.java.net (download.java.net)... 216.68.101.35,216.68.101.32 
Connecting to download.java.net (download.java.net)|216.68.101.35|:80... connected. 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 
2017-09-22 02:51:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.
download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed. 
dpkg: error processingpackage oracle-java9-installer (--configure):  subprocess installed
post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:  oracle-java9-installer  
E: Sub-process/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The URL for the download is now different: New URL: http://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk9/9/binaries/jdk-9+181_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz Unfortunately I was unable to make the required changes to the files similar to those suggestions in your first linked post. URL and hash source: http://jdk.java.net/9/

Comment: So I guess you have to wait for the PPA maintainers to update the installation script.

Comment: A solution can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/958284/673247

Comment: The team website is at https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team , the code maybe can be browsed at https://code.launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/oracle-jdk-installer/trunk ? Where is the source code for these packages?

Comment: Why this question is got closed ??? it is not duplicate